# Rails Ajax формы

Tags: ajax, ruby, ruby-on-rails

Пытаюсь понять как работает Ajax в рельсах. Вопрос 1 есть ли решение лучше чем в примере?

**views -> ajax -> show.html.erb**

```
<h1>Ajax show</h1>
Click this link to show the current 
<%= link_to "time", ajax_time_path, remote: true %>.<br/>
<div id='time_div'>
</div>
```

**views -> ajax -> time.js.erb**

```
$('#time_div').html("The current time is <%= Time.now.to_s %>");
```

Вопрос 2 - как грамотно, используя Ajax добавить информацию в БД?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Обычное нормальное решение
2. Обрабатывайте форму в контроллере также, как и обычную, только добавьте ей атрибут "remote: true".

Comment: Спасибо, работает:

<%= form_for(@post, :remote => true) do |f| %>
  ...
<% end %>